# Difference between AWS Elastic Container Service's (ECS) ExecutionRole and TaskRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I'm using AWS's CloudFormation, and I recently spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out why the role I had created and attached policies to was not enabling my ECS task to send a message to a Simple Queue Service (SQS) queue.

I realized that I was incorrectly attaching the SQS permissions policy to the `Execution Role` when I should have been attaching the policy to the `Task Role`. I cannot find good documentation that explains the difference between the two roles. CloudFormation documentation for the two of them are here: [ExecutionRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-executionrolearn) and [TaskRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-taskrolearn)

Comment: "I recently spent quite a bit of time" hits too close to home! :-)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Referring to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html)  you can see that the execution role is the IAM role that executes ECS actions such as pulling the image and storing the application logs in cloudwatch.

The TaskRole then, is the IAM role used by the task itself. For example, if your container wants to call other AWS services like S3, SQS, etc then those permissions would need to be covered by the TaskRole.

Using a TaskRole is functionally the same as using access keys in a config file on the container instance. **Using access keys in this way is not secure and is considered very bad practice.** I include this in the answer because many people reading this already understand access keys.

Comment: Anyway best practice is using attached IAM role rather locally stored access keys.

Comment: There are also [Container Instance Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html). The important thing to note is that your containers will automatically be able to use these roles as well. So best practice is to have the Container instance Roles at minimum, and extend it (if needed) by task roles.

Comment: What is the best practice, should task role and task execution role be the same role or two different roles?

Comment: This is a good primer on the described differences https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKhtSmYRfxs

Answer (score 43):

ECS task execution role is capabilities of ECS agent (and container instance), e.g:

- Pulling a container image from Amazon ECR
- Using the awslogs log driver

ECS task role is specific capabilities within the task itself, e.g:

- When your actual code runs

Answer (score 2):

The Execution Role is for the ECS service. The Task Role is for the task.

Answer (score 0):

All answers provided so far are correct. Adding my version, in an attempt to make it bit easier for those who still need further clarification.

**Task Role:**
The ECS set up will have some containers. These containers will perform some tasks for which we are being created. To perform these tasks **containers** need to call other AWS services. Which services can be called is defined by the **Task Role**. So, this is ***container's role*** required for a task.

**Task Execution Role:**
To set up the containers and maintain these, some tasks are performed. **Container Agent** performs these tasks for the container. So, the role required & assumed by Container Agent is Task Execution Role.