# Set the name of an automatically created Role in the CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

For example, when making a task definition:

```js
const taskDefinition = new ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(this, 'TaskDefinition', {
  networkMode: ecs.NetworkMode.AWS_VPC,
})
```

This makes the role automatically, and named automatically.

From the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition.html), there is property to set the role, but it accepts `IRole` not name.

Is there any method to name the role which is automatically created?

Alternatively, I suppose I should use [class Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.Role.html) to make role in advance and attache this to the `Ec2TaskDefinition`?, however how can I know the role property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ECS TaskDefinition has two role props, the [executionRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.TaskDefinition.html#executionrole) and the [taskRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.TaskDefinition.html#taskrole).<sup>1</sup>  If you pass a role construct to these props, you can set the role name directly.  If you don't set the props, you can use [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) syntax to modify the name of the automatically created default roles:

```js
if (!taskDefinition.taskRole) {
    throw new Error("The Task Role is undefined");
}

const cfnTaskRole = taskDefinition.taskRole.node.defaultChild as iam.CfnRole;

cfnTaskRole.addPropertyOverride("RoleName", "my-task-role");
```

---

[1] See [Difference between AWS Elastic Container Service's (ECS) ExecutionRole and TaskRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999472/difference-between-aws-elastic-container-services-ecs-executionrole-and-taskr)

Comment: It works perfect for me! And I learned about `taskRole` and `executionRole`. It coud be help for further problem. thank you very much!